# Converting date stored as a varchar

Tags: ssms, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm creating a query that has a column of dates stored as a VARCHAR in the format DD-MMM-YYYY.

Could you tell me how I can convert this into date format please?

I don't want to alter the original table in any way, as it's not mine to tinker!

Comment: It's ok, I've used a CAST to convert.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to convert your `VARCHAR` value into `DATE` format.

Syntax for CAST:

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
```

---

Sample execution: You can convert into DATE alone or DATETIME format:

```
DECLARE @TestDate AS VARCHAR (12) = '22-MAY-2015';
SELECT CAST(@TestDate AS DATE);
```

Output: `2015-05-22`

```
DECLARE @TestDate1 AS VARCHAR (12) = '22-MAY-2015';
SELECT CAST(@TestDate1 AS DATETIME);
```

Output: `2015-05-22 00:00:00.000`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CONVERT` when converting between `date`/`datetime` and `varchar` datatypes.

[Relying on implicit conversion for date formats can give unexpected results](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/).

By using `CONVERT` you are able to explicitly specify [date & time styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles) for your data. Date format of DD-MMM-YYYY, corresponds to date format 105, so you could use something like this:

```
DECLARE @TestDate AS VARCHAR (12) = '06-MAR-2017';
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@TestDate,105);
```

For additional reasons on why to favor `CONVERT` over `CAST`, [this article has some more examples](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-cast-vs-convert/).